# pandas select row if value in another column changs

Tags: python, pandas, longitudinal

Let's say I have a large data set that follows a similar structure:

[image]

where the id repeats multiple times. I would like to select any id where the value in column b changed with the desired output as such:

[image]

How might I be able to achieve that via pandas?

Comment: Please NEVER post dataframes as images, only as text and ideally as Python code to create the df, as in my answer below. Other useful tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking for. You say

> I would like to select any id where the value in column b changed

but 'changed' from what?

Perhaps the following can be helpful -- it will show you all unique ColumnB strings for each id

Using a sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'colb':['a','a','b','c','d','c','c']})
```

we use `groupby` and `unique`:

```
df.groupby('id')['colb'].unique().explode().to_frame()
```

output:

```
    colb
id  
1   a
1   b
2   c
2   d
```

so for id=1 we have a and b as unique phrases, and for id=2 we have c and d